# Force ssh to use a particular algorithm for host identification

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

I am trying to better understand how `ssh` does [host authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20710/94605).  I am ssh'ing from a macbook pro (OSX 10.14.6) to several CentOS 8.1 servers.  There are several files on the remote CentOS servers in `/etc/ssh/` that are used for the host-based authentication (e.g. `ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub`, `ssh_host_dsa_key.pub`, `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`).

If I look at my macbook's local `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, I see entries that use `ssh-rsa` which corresponds to `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`.  I also see entries for `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` which correspond to `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`.

**Question** :

1. When I `ssh` into my remote server, is there a way for me to force `ssh` to use a particular algorithm for the host authentication or is this something that I'll have to change by hand in `known_hosts`?  E.g. force it to use `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` instead of `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`.
2. How does `ssh` by default decide which algorithm to use for host authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-o` flag to specify options for SSH. One of these options is `HostKeyAlgorithms` which will control which algorithms your client offers, see: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.

If you run ssh with the `-vv` flag you can see the offer that is made by your client. Then the server chooses the first algorithm used by the client that it supports. I would guess that the different support different algorithms.